# Python Algorithm adding points for curves

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement the Double-and-Add Algorithm for Elliptic curves, which is done below. However, I am not producing the same answers as the textbook. Instead I am getting a repeat answer. Is there anything wrong with the code?

The code should do the following:

1. Input: Point, P, and an integer n greater than or equal to 1.
2. Set Q=P and R=(0,0).
3. Loop while n>0.
4. If n=1 mod 2, set R=R+Q.
5. Set Q=2Q and n=floor(n/2)
6. If n>0, continue with loop at Step 3.
7. Return the point R, which equals nP.

   ```
   def doubleandadd(n, A, B, p, (x,y)):
       P=(x,y)
       Q,R=P,(0,0)
       while n>0:
           if (n%2)==1:
               R=R+Q
           Q,n=2*Q,math.floor(n/2)
       print R
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `tuple`s for your points, but the `+` operator concatenates tuples, rather than adding their values together. Similarly, multiplying a tuple by an integer repeats the tuple's values, rather than multiplying each of them.

I suggest using a numerical type like `numpy`'s `array`s instead (or just adding the components of the tuples yourself, if you don't want to use `numpy`).

Comment: How would I do this using numpy?